# Show that for a field $F$, the polynomial ring $F[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$ is not a PID for $n>1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

**I want clarification of the following solution:**

Let $I=(x_1)+(x_2)$ be an ideal of $F[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$. Then if $I=(f)$ is principal then we must have $f \in F \backslash \{0\}$ since $\gcd(x_1, x_2)=1$ and $f \mid x_1,\ f \mid x_2$. Why?

But $I \cap F =\{0\}$. Why?

Contradiction, why?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694468/why-is-the-polynomial-ring-of-more-than-one-variable-not-a-pid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.** $(x_1,x_2)=(f)\implies x_1\in(f),x_2\in(f)$.

If $a∈I∩F$ then $a=x_1g+x_2h$ and for $x_1=x_2=0$ we get...